# Running count for each 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to calculate running count for each 2 rows like below,

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
     EmpId INT, 
     Yr INT, 
     Sales DECIMAL(8,2)
)

INSERT INTO sales (EmpId, Yr, Sales)
VALUES (1, 2005, 12000), (1, 2006, 18000), (1, 2007, 25000),
       (1, 2008, 25000), (1, 2009, 25000),
       (2, 2005, 15000), (2, 2006, 6000), (2, 2007, 6000)

SELECT 
    EmpId, Yr, sales, 
    SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY empid ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS TotalSales2
FROM 
    sales
```

Output:

```
EmpId   Yr      sales   TotalSales2
-----------------------------------
  1     2005    12000      12000
  1     2006    18000      30000
  1     2007    25000      55000
  1     2008    25000      68000
  1     2009    25000      75000
  2     2005    15000      15000
  2     2006     6000      21000
  2     2007     6000      27000
```

But expected output:

```
EmpId   Yr     Sales    TotalSales2
-----------------------------------
  1     2005    12000   12000
  1     2006    18000   30000
  1     2007    25000   25000   
  1     2008    25000   50000
  1     2009    25000   25000   
  2     2005    15000   15000
  2     2006     6000   21000
  2     2007     6000    6000
```

What am I doing wrong in this query?

**Note**: SQL Servre version is 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression:

```
SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY empid 
                 ORDER BY empid 
                 ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

calculates the sum considering *the current row and the 2 rows* immediately preceding it. So it actually calculates a rolling sum, which is what you really don't want.

I think you are actually looking for something like the following:

```
;WITH CTE_Group AS (
    SELECT EmpId, Yr, sales,        
          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY yr) + 1 ) / 2 AS grp
    FROM sales      
)
SELECT EmpId, Yr, sales,
       SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY empid, grp 
                        ORDER BY yr) AS TotalSales2
FROM CTE_Group
```

The above query uses a `CTE` in order to calculate field `grp`: the value of this field is `1` for the first two records of an `empid` partition, `2` for the next two records, and so on.

Using `grp` we can calculate the running total of `sales` for groups of 2 as is the requirement of the OP.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/OYBPVO81678)

Edit:

To offset a larger group of records try using (credit goes to @Max Szczurek for pointing this out):

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY yr) - 1 ) / n AS grp
```

where `n` is the number of records each group contains.

Comment: Suggest changing (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY yr) + 1 ) / 2 AS grp - change the +1 to a -1, and then this works for larger group sizes. +1 works for group size of 2, but offsets larger groups in the wrong direction!

Comment: what can i do if i want to find running total for first 12 rows and another 12 rows of each EmpId?

Comment: @MaxSzczurek Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT EmpId, Yr, Sales, 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY yr) % 2 = 0 
    THEN sales + lag(sales, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY yr) 
    ELSE sales 
    END AS TotalSales2
FROM sales
```

Lag returns the previous row's value - when row_number() is even, add the current row's value to the previous row - otherwise, just show the sales for the current row. Partition each by EmpId, order each by yr - output matches the expected.

Also, thanks so much for adding the DDL/sample data.

Comment: Consider adding some commentary to your answer,

Comment: My bad! Added some notes.

Comment: thats awsome. But i am quit not understand your query. what can i do if i want to find running count for each 12 rows ?

Comment: LAG specifically returns the last record within the partition - it returns the last record based on the ORDER BY - in this case, since it's ordered by yr, it gets the value from the previous year. LAG is perfect for getting the previous row, but to extend the answer to group by rows of 12, the CTE in Giorgos' answer would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Although answer is already accepted, consider below query also. This will give the required output :

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE(EmpId INT, Yr INT, Sales DECIMAL(8,2))

INSERT INTO @sales ( EmpId, Yr, Sales )
VALUES  (1, 2005, 12000),
      (1, 2006, 18000),
      (1, 2007, 25000),
      (1, 2008, 25000),
      (1, 2009, 25000),
      (2, 2005, 15000),
      (2, 2006, 6000),
      (2, 2007, 6000)
;WITH SAMPLE_DATA
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by empid order by (select 100))SNO,* FROM     @Sales
)
SELECT EmpId,Yr,Sales
    ,CASE WHEN (SNO%2=0)
     THEN SALES+
    (
        SELECT Sales FROM SAMPLE_DATA T2 WHERE T2.EmpId=T1.EmpId AND     T2.SNO=T1.SNO-1
    )
    ELSE Sales END 
TotalSales2
FROM SAMPLE_DATA T1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
--------------------------------------
--EmpId Yr  Sales   TotalSales2
--------------------------------------
1   2005    12000.00    12000.00
1   2006    18000.00    30000.00
1   2007    25000.00    25000.00
1   2008    25000.00    50000.00
1   2009    25000.00    25000.00
2   2005    15000.00    15000.00
2   2006    6000.00     21000.00
2   2007    6000.00     6000.00
--------------------------------------
```